# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type exception with dates after 1753/1/1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added a property to my **Customer** Model, created a migration and updated the database. The field created in DB is **datetime**.
here is my Model code

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

here is the view that is actually a form where I insert date and other fields and submit the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate, "{0: dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

and here is the Action in the controller

```
     public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer.Id == 0)
        {
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        }
        else
        {
            var customerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
            customerInDb = customer;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
    }
```

I have papulated the BirthDate field with 23/04/1976 and debug the application and check the value of customer.BirthDate which is 23/04/1976 12:00:00 AM. The date is note before 1753/1/1 but I m receiving the said exception.

I have also tried the following:
Make the field nullable by

```
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

the exception is gone but the date is not being saved to the database.

Removed the formate "{0: dd-MM-yyy}" from the view but in vain.

Inserted dates in different formats e.g. 23-Apr-1952, 1985-12-01 and 1987/1/2 but didn't work.

Visual Studio 2013 and Database is **LocalDb** of visual studio.

Comment: What is the exact exception message, and which line is throwing it?

Comment: Is that the only `DateTime` property in your `Customer` class?

Comment: Exception is: "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" and line is "_context.SaveChanges();"

Comment: There are other porperties but those are working fine. I have checked.

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon Are you sure? `DateTime` properties are set to `DateTime.Min` by default, and it will try to set those in the database when you save the record, even if you don't set them manually. Try changing all your `DateTime` properties to `DateTime?`.

Comment: This is the only property in this model with DateTime type and I have already tried DateTime?. It removes the exception but the input value doesn't save to the database. Note the values of other properties are successfully saved to the database.

Comment: Debug and set a breakpoint at `if (customer.Id == 0)`. At that point, does `customer.BirthDate` have a value?

Comment: What is the culture on the server? If it is not one that expects dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, then `BirthDate` would not bind and it will be `DateTime.MinValue` which generates your error. And at the very least you should be check `ModelState.IsValid` before saving data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the error goes away by making the property nullable gives the answer. If a value *was* being set, then you would get exactly the same error as when the field was **not** nullable.

Therefore, the value is not being set, which stores a null if the field is nullable (confirmed by you saying it doesn't store the value - it's storing null).

So for a not-nullable property, when it isn't set, it will have the default value for a dot net `DateTime`, which is `DateTime.MinValue`, which would be valid if stored in an SQL server `datetime2` but not in a `datetime`, where you get the 1753 error.

By the way, I'm assuming this LocalDb is basically SQL server, based on the 1753 error. For the record, in SQL server you should be using datetime2: [DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server)

But this field is actually a Date, so you should be using the `date` SQL type.

So in summary, I suspect the BirthDate value in the Customer passed to the Save method has the value DateTime.MinValue. Now you need to work out why... (but that's a different question)

P.S. Are you using `dd-MM-yyy` on purpose? Should there be an extra `y`?

Comment: Question updated. it is "yyyy". but I think the fourth y doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem lies in both `DateTime` viewmodel property and this `TextBoxFor` helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate, "{0: dd-MM-yyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Depending on current culture setting, this will generate plain input with specified date format which may not matched with current culture setting in server, which causing default model binder to ignore its value and uses `DateTime.MinValue` as default value (because it's not a nullable type), which doesn't fit for `datetime` column type in SQL that has minimum value of `1753-01-01` (the equivalent type of `System.DateTime` in T-SQL is `datetime2`).

The most recommended setup to create input helper for `DateTime` property is using `DataTypeAttribute` set to `DataType.Date` and `DisplayFormatAttribute` to specify the format string:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Then, use either `EditorFor` or `TextBoxFor` with `type="date"` attribute to generate date input:

```
@* TextBoxFor *@
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Customer.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" }) 

@* EditorFor *@         
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**Note:** The same setup like above also apply for `Nullable<DateTime>`/`DateTime?` property.

Additionally you should check for `IsValid` property of `ModelState` before using `SaveChanges()` and return the same view when validation failed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (customer.Id == 0)
        {
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        }
        else
        {
            var customerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
            customerInDb = customer;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
    }
    else
    {
        // validation failed, show the form again with validation errors
        return View(customer);
    }
}
```

Related issue: [ASP.NET MVC date not saving when posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589346/asp-net-mvc-date-not-saving-when-posting)

Comment: If you use `EditorFor()` then it needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) - refer [Date does not display from Model on HTML input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097748/date-does-not-display-from-model-on-html-input-type-date/31097864#31097864), and if using `TextBoxFor()` there is no point using either the `[DataType]` or `[DisplayFormat]` attributes (they are ignored), and you still need to specify the format in the 2nd parameter